# computing rolling averages by integer days in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I have taken some data from a csv and put it into a dataframe:

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv('C:\...', delimiter = ',', encoding = 'utf-8')
df2 = df.groupby(['i-j','day'])['i-j'].agg({'count'})
```

[image: dataframe]

I would like to calculate for each 'i-j' the seven day moving average of their count. First I think I need to add the days with zero count to the table. Is there an easy way to do this by modifying my code above? In other words I would like missing values to count as 0.

Then I would need to add another column to the dataframe that calculates the average of count for each i-j for the previous seven-days. Do I need to convert the days to something that pandas recognizes as a date value in order to use some of the rolling statistical functions? Or can I just change the type of the 'date' column and proceed.

Many thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but given your starting DataFrame of `df2` the following should work.

First reindex `df2` to fill in the missing days with zeros:

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), range(31)])
df2 = df2.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)
```

(I'm assuming you want 31 days, but you can change this as necessary.)

Now if you `unstack` this reindexed DataFrame and take the transpose, you have a DataFrame where each column is an entry of `i-j` and contains the counts per day:

```
df2.unstack().T
```

You can calculate the rolling mean of this DataFrame:

```
rm = pd.rolling_mean(df2.unstack().T, 7)
```

To finish, you can `stack` this frame of rolling means to get back to the shape of the original reindexed `df2`:

```
rm.T.stack(dropna=False)
```

Comment: it seems that the reindex(new_index, fill_value=0) is setting everything in the count column to 0. 
ie in the code below df2 is the same as above while df3 has an entry for every day but count = 0 everywhere.
`code df2 = df.groupby(['i-j','day'])['i-j'].agg({'count'})

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df2.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), range(30)])

df3 = df2.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)`

Comment: Hmmm - that shouldn't happen unless none of the indexes in the existing DataFrame are in `new_index`. Perhaps the `day` column contains strings not integers?

Comment: that's exactly what was wrong. forcing the date column to integer fixes this. thanks again